# Having trouble getting 12.10 to work with my newly built PC. I think the problem is with the graphics

Tags: ati

edit: I know that I am generally ignorant of Linux and computers in general, but I did do a lot of research on my own before asking for help.

I use an AMD A10-5800K APU with Radeon HD 7660D

So far, I've got ubuntu installed but I've had to insert "nomodeset" when booting or otherwise the screen becomes extremely squished and jittery.

I could edit the grub file in etc/default to fix that problem, but there's no resolution option for my display so I still wouldn't be able to use the default driver.

I tried the two alternative drivers in the Additional Drivers tab in Software Sources; they didn't require nomodeset and had much more acceptable (but not perfect) resolution options, but they broke Unity.

I tried installing AMD's latest stable Catalyst driver with an installation program I found online, but that didn't appear to do anything but "break packages" (not sure what that means, but it sounds bad).

Also, Compiz crashes multiple times when I first run Software Updater after an install.

I just did a fresh install and did the nomodeset thing at boot, but have done nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

[Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_radeon_hd7660d&num=1)  Lists what version of driver and open GL he used to test the same setup u have.  Its not much of an answer but might point u in a direction to get the answer you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

edit: I actually scanned through that article earlier but had trouble figuring out how to install everything I needed to install any catalyst driver so went with an auto-installer I found on the fan club website. This time I'll try harder to find the exact driver he used and install it.

Comment: It seems the versions listed in the above article can be found in the 12.10 repositories.  Ubuntu 12.10 repository (fglrx 9.0.2 / OpenGL 4.2.11903)